# macOS Sierra: parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>

Tags: keychain, error, macos

Yesterday I (clean) installed macOS sierra and since then I'm having a particular error message in my console every few milliseconds, that I can't seem to find anywhere!

```
error   05:58:28.906530 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
```

Every 10-20 instances of the above error, I also get the following ones

```
error   05:58:24.034105 +0300   parsecd network_config_has_proxies_configured network_config_has_proxies_configured is deprecated
error   05:58:24.034148 +0300   parsecd tcp_connection_get_remote API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
error   05:58:24.034242 +0300   parsecd tcp_connection_is_cellular API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
```

and occasionally I also get the one bellow

```
error   05:51:39.662197 +0300   parsecd Server endpoint not set, data can't be sent to server
```

I've tried creating a new user account, but the error appears there too.
In my system I have two input sources (english and greek) - At some point I assumed it's related to the dictation service and/or siri (that I had both already disabled). So I reenabled them but no luck whatsoever.

I also get the following events that prompted me to think that this might be some keychain related issue - I wonder what that might be though (I didn't use keychain, and I have icloud keychain disabled)

```
default 06:16:15.444813 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 06:16:15.444919 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
```

Anybody having some idea on how to solve this?
Thank you!

a fragment of all the parsecd related events follow:

```
default 05:37:43.773971 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71af2ba90 free /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db buffer 0x10a60c000
default 05:37:43.774392 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ad4ba70 free /Library/Keychains/System.keychain buffer 0x7fb71b832600
default 05:37:45.487085 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:37:45.487296 +0300   parsecd subsystem: com.apple.securityd, category: kcnotify, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
error   05:37:54.873887 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:37:54.873950 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[9] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:37:54.952336 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:37:54.952411 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[10] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:37:55.099456 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:37:55.099509 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[11] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:37:55.199765 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:37:55.199818 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[12] <private>, reply <private>
default 05:37:59.931671 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:08.374250 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Event [1:0x7fb71ac2b0b0]: 2 Err(0)
default 05:38:08.374313 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Cancel [1:0x7fb71ac2b0b0]
default 05:38:08.374397 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Destroyed [1:0x7fb71ac2b0b0]
default 05:38:30.621014 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:30.621187 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:30.635354 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:30.635518 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:30.646170 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:38:30.646330 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.391402 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.391613 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.407717 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.407870 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.418649 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:22.418812 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:27.235445 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:27.235726 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.581474 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.581638 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.596375 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.596526 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.607261 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:39:52.607421 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.760225 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.760396 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.774705 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.774850 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.785715 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:22.785906 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.845742 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.845911 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.861012 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.861172 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.871318 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:40:52.871475 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.097249 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.097465 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.111622 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.111779 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.122738 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:23.122884 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.295645 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.295870 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.312028 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.312170 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.323217 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:41:53.323383 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db (0 1 1 1)
default 05:42:06.251726 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 05:42:06.251995 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
default 05:42:06.252950 +0300   parsecd DbOpen of /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsObject.db
default 05:42:06.253051 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ac330f0 opened /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsObject.db: 4636 bytes
default 05:42:06.253115 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ac330f0 allocated /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsObject.db buffer 0x7fb71c021e00 size 4636
default 05:42:06.253181 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ac330f0 closed /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsObject.db
default 05:42:06.253620 +0300   parsecd DbOpen of /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsDirectory.db
default 05:42:06.253688 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae4fde0 opened /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsDirectory.db: 50744 bytes
default 05:42:06.253759 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae4fde0 allocated /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsDirectory.db buffer 0x7fb71c041000 size 4
default 05:42:06.253794 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae4fde0 closed /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsDirectory.db
default 05:42:06.253819 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae4fde0 free /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsDirectory.db buffer 0x7fb71c041000
default 05:42:06.253927 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ac330f0 free /var/folders/k3/gn_tkxgd4pn3k_qw7xwc0w640000gn/C//mds/mdsObject.db buffer 0x7fb71c021e00
default 05:42:06.254054 +0300   parsecd DbOpen of /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
default 05:42:06.254154 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae51120 opened /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db: 191880 bytes
default 05:42:06.254408 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae51120 allocated /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db buffer 0x10a60c000 size 191880
default 05:42:06.254642 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae51120 closed /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
default 05:42:06.256503 +0300   parsecd loading /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
default 05:42:06.259143 +0300   parsecd not attempting migration for /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db version 512 (1 1 0)
default 05:42:06.259251 +0300   parsecd DbOpen of /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
default 05:42:06.259355 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae56740 opened /Library/Keychains/System.keychain: 35880 bytes
default 05:42:06.259426 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae56740 allocated /Library/Keychains/System.keychain buffer 0x7fb71c036000 size 35880
default 05:42:06.259462 +0300   parsecd 0x7fb71ae56740 closed /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
default 05:42:06.260905 +0300   parsecd loading /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
default 05:42:06.263639 +0300   parsecd not attempting migration for /Library/Keychains/System.keychain version 256 (0 0 1)
default 05:42:06.263789 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 05:42:06.263838 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
default 05:42:06.263960 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 05:42:06.263998 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
default 05:42:06.264089 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 05:42:06.264210 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
default 05:42:06.264346 +0300   parsecd switching to keychain-db: /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db from /Users/thisuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain (0 1 0 1)
default 05:42:06.264382 +0300   parsecd not switching as we're not in ~/Library/Keychains/: /Library/Keychains/System.keychain (0)
error   05:42:06.264613 +0300   parsecd network_config_has_proxies_configured network_config_has_proxies_configured is deprecated
error   05:42:06.264675 +0300   parsecd tcp_connection_get_remote API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
default 05:42:06.264735 +0300   parsecd TIC Enabling TLS [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]
error   05:42:06.264765 +0300   parsecd tcp_connection_is_cellular API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
default 05:42:06.264791 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Start [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]
error   05:42:06.637066 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:06.637121 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[14] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:42:06.793959 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:06.794011 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[15] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:42:06.961645 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:06.961698 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[16] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:42:07.017000 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:07.017058 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[17] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:42:07.193562 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:07.193621 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[18] <private>, reply <private>
error   05:42:07.332684 +0300   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
default 05:42:07.332740 +0300   parsecd session <private> performing query[19] <private>, reply <private>
default 05:42:09.119223 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 2, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.120634 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 11, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.121393 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 12, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.121543 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 14, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.156583 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Trust Result [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 0
default 05:42:09.821718 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 4, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.821824 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 20, Pending(0)
default 05:42:09.822186 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 1 Err(0)
default 05:42:09.822210 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Connected [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: Err(0)
default 05:42:09.822287 +0300   parsecd TIC TCP Conn Event [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]: 8 Err(0)
default 05:42:09.822315 +0300   parsecd TIC TLS Handshake Complete [2:0x7fb71ae71a10]
```

Comment: Though it doesn't have any answers yet, this looks like the same problem/question as http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255794/12285 — you might want to keep tabs on that page as well. Welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: thank you @timothymh for the tip! At the very least, it seems related (even though I haven't used safari) - I'll keep an eye on it!

Answer (score 1):

I had never seen "parsecd" or "keyboardserviced" until the other day, when my keyboard seemed to be sticky and slow. I could type three or four characters (or keys) before any appeared on the Facebook page as part of a comment that I was writing. Then "parsecd" popped up for approval from my "Little Snitch" app. I allowed it after reading the details. Now, knock on wood, there does not seem to be any stickiness or delays with my keyboard. This may be part of a patch as a result of recent updates from the Apple App Store, including MacOS Sierra. I also started using "private browsing" around the same time. In retrospect, private browsing seems to be related to the sticky keys as well. In addition, I had been changing my login password and then found that I was blocked from "keychain access" I learned that the best way to prevent this blockage is to change my login password only through . As the administrator, it seems I can change the password of any other user on this same Mac. But when I change the passwords for other users, the "keychain access" password for that user does not change. To effectively change the login password for any user, that user must be logged in, and to change it through  which then changes his "keychain access" password at the same time. This is only my opinion, which is offered as an observation. Any relationship to the actual problem may be purely coincidental. My keyboard keys are getting a little sticky again during the creation of thus message.

Comment: The words "System preferences/ Users and Groups" did not appear two places in my post 22 minutes ago. My intention was to say that the best way to change a login password is through system preferences/ Users & Groups. This changes the keychain access password to the same password at the same time. Otherwise, keychain access may be blocked, with no notification to the user. It took a while for this to become obvious, and a while longer to track it down. Apple Care did not suggest in a phone call to change login passwords through System preferences/ Users & Groups.

Comment: Interesting points @Jim Logan! Never thought of linking these errors to the lag that I was also experiencing! I'm certain that I installed Little snitch much later so it must be unrelated. While my console finally stopped showing the errors with yesterday's macOS update (10.12.12) the lag was still here and I finally decided to pinpoint it; Only chrome (currently 55) has the issue; safari and firefox work just fine - I disable hardware acceleration for Chrome (mid 2011 iMac/AMD Radeon HD 6750M) and the lag vanished! Still looking into it!

Comment: the parsecd issue seems to be back

Comment: “Parsecd” handles Siri suggestions - so if your firewall is blocking inter process communications, that’s far more likely the cause of keyboard hangs. My experience is that these errors are never functional and indicating an error and more for diagnostic and activity logging.

Answer (score 1):

This process helps sandbox and protect information and isn’t an indication that anything is wrong. Specifically, it manages the Siri data and access - so unless you have a specific problem with Siri not working, I would simply ignore those messages since they are debugging / status pointers and not something you need to take action on.

From the manual page:

> parsecd manages access and data for Siri Suggestions

It also mentions that there are no configuration items and "Users should not run parsecd manually".